# Artifactory LDAP Manager DN Setting

Tags: ldap, artifactory

I am trying to set up a new Artifactory Server and set it up with AD Authentication via LDAP but not having much luck.

I believe the Manager DN is looking for the RDN for a object (not a OU) with read rights on Active Dictory and therefore I have tired the following;

```
cn=Admin,cn=UserGroup1,ou=Groups,ou=Security Groups,DC=blah,DC=COM
```

Which gives me the below error message from %ARTIFACTORY_HOME%\Logs

```
Authentication failed. Probably a wrong manager dn or manager password: [LDAP: error code 49 .....
```

Many thanks

ps - the user name and password are correct.

Comment: Coincidentally, I've run in to the same problem with an Artifactory 3.4.2 installation. You may want to add which version of Artifactory you're running to the post.

Comment: Hey @StefanWalter your right, version detail would help - Running Artifactory Version 4.4.2

Answer (score 1):

So after speaking with my internal IT they were able to drill down into Active Directory and provide the full DN path of the manager DN account.

-Updated the path at the end of the LDAP URL
-Updated the manager DN path

After this every think worked great !!